# Clustering key columns must exactly match columns in CLUSTERING ORDER BY directive

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

I am trying to create cluster column using the create query

```
CREATE TABLE videos_by_tag (
       tag text,
       video_id uuid,
       added_date timestamp,
       title text,
       PRIMARY KEY ((tag), added_date, video_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(added_date DESC);
```

It's showing the following error. Am i missing something in the create table ?

InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Clustering key columns must exactly match columns in CLUSTERING ORDER BY directive"

It's working only if i include all the clustering columns mentioned in the primary key( in this case added_date, video_id). Is it mandatory to include all the columns from the primary key in clustering order by?

```
CREATE TABLE videos_by_tag (
       tag text,
       video_id uuid,
       added_date timestamp,
       title text,
       PRIMARY KEY ((tag), added_date, video_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(added_date DESC,video_id ASC);
```

I am using the following version of cassandra on mac os

[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 4.0.0.680 | CQL spec 3.4.5

It's working only if i include all the clustering columns mentioned in the primary key( in this case added_date, video_id). Is it mandatory to include all the columns from the primary key in clustering order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the question was also posted on https://community.datastax.com/questions/4118/ and I'm re-posting my answer here.

Yes, it is mandatory to specify all the clustering columns in the `CLUSTERING ORDER BY` directive in DataStax Enterprise 6.8.0. The logic for `CREATE TABLE` was changed in Apache Cassandra 4.0-alpha1 ([CASSANDRA-13426](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13426)) but has been reverted back in C* 4.0-alpha4 ([CASSANDRA-15271](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15271)). The previous [accepted] behaviour will be included in a future release of DSE 6.8. Cheers!

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "the previous [accepted] behaviour will be included in a future release of DSE 6.8". Can you please elaborate on this topic? DSE 6.8.4 currently requires all clustering columns to be named in the `CLUSTERING ORDER BY` part. Will DSE continue to enforce this and be out of sync with Cassandra in this regard, or will it go back allowing to leave out the explicit naming of all columns? If so, from which version on?

Comment: The previous behaviour was to allow table creations without specifying all clustering columns but CASSANDRA-13426 changed that norm. It was reverted in CASSANDRA-15271 to go back to the previously accepted behaviour. Cheers!

Comment: That I understood. My question was more targeted towards how this correlates with the  DSE versions. We're about to install 6.8.4 where the above is an issue. In versions later than that it will not be an issue anymore?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely read your follow up question. DSE is ahead of OSS C*. C-15271 is done in C* 4.0 which is not released yet. We will implement 15271 in a future release of DSE. Cheers!